# Views content panes link to view

Tags: views, panels

I have a view with multiple content panes and multiple pages. With the content pane, I have used the feature "Link to view" before to get the title of the pane to link to the page view. When using this before, there has only been one pane and one view, which has worked well.

Now I would like to link multiple panes up to different pages within the same view. When selecting "yes" in "Link to view", it always links to the first page. Is there a way to specify which page I would like to link my panes to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out you can directly insert html into view titles and it will work. Wrapping the different view panes in an `<a>` tag solved the issue.